# How to install the 64-bit version for Windows 10 of Graphviz 2.38

Tags: 64-bit, graphviz, windows-10-desktop, installation-package

The Graphviz download page has to links, one for a .msi file and another for a .zip

when running the .msi, it looks that it's for 32 bits, since the default directory installation is "Program Files (x86)", which is where the 32-bit installations go.

There are no instructions on what to do with the .zip

Has anyone installed the 64-bit version of Graphviz? Is there an installation script that installs the executables?  If so, where can I find it?
(I hope it exists, because I can't compile source code in my machine.)

Many thanks in advance,

Alex

Comment: Your question seems to be off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

A litte late, but in case someone needs an answer : By now, there seems to be no official 64bit support by graphviz. 
I found a discussion on github about graphviz for python where you can find a link to a github repository, that leading to an [adapted graphviz solution for Visual Studio with 64bit support](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/58).
In [another discussion](https://github.com/ellson/MOTHBALLED-graphviz/issues/1244) on github a link to an [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ellson/graphviz) project is provided, which also includes a 64bit configuration. Unfortunately this one seems to be abandoned.